# Sonatype Nexus: How to circumvent when unavailable?

Tags: conda, nexus3

It can happen that the internal sonatype nexus manager is not available like in case of vpn issues. What can I do to still be able to download packages in that case?

Even when explicitly setting a channel like in below example

```
conda install -c conda-forge numpy
```

I still get a http error that connection to nexus server failed

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://nexus-manager/repository/anaconda-proxy/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -
```

I suspect this is because existing packages have been installed via nexus. Can this somehow be circumvented? That I can install even when nexus repo is not available?

UPDATE:
completely removing the channels to internal repo from .condarc makes the http error go away but now it seems conda still can't figure out how to install as it's stuck in solving environment (not sure if this would have happened either way. I'm just making a new environment as that seems to work for now but isn't really a permanent solution.